# Testing "Facebook Login" locally

Tags: facebook, authentication, dns, localhost, facebook-login

I am trying to locally test my "Continue With Facebook" button. I get this error telling me the URL is invalid. Below is how I have configured my app's OAuth settings. Based on all my research this is configured correctly but something is still wrong.

I am using npm http-server to run a local instance of my site. It is running on localhost:8080

[image: Err]

[image: Fb settings]

[image]

[image]

As per the last image, it wont let me add domain such as "http://localhost:8080". It only lets me add "localhost"

Comment: _“As per the last image, it wont let me add domain such as "`http://localhost:8080`". It only lets me add "localhost"”_ - congrats, you just found out the difference between a domain name, and a URL ...

Comment: Go check what value the parameter redirect_uri has in your login dialog call (browser address bar). That exact value must be in your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field.

Answer (score 2):

If your actual production URL is **domain.com** then in FB > Settings > App Domains, add the additional URL **local.domain.com**. Then on your local machine in the /etc/hosts file (or [Windows equivalent](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/10c/local-dns-modifications-on-windows-etchosts-equivalent.html)) add the entry:

```
127.0.0.1 local.domain.com
```

In a browser, navigate to local.domain.com and that URL will be served up by your local machine (i.e. localhost). This will keep Facebook Login happy while running a test / development version.

You'll also need to whitelist your machine's IP (in FB > Settings > Advanced > Security > Server IP Whitelist) and add an additional **http://local.domain.com/callback** (in FB > Facebook login > Settings > Valid OAuth redirect URIs).